# Is it possible to overwrite with a SSIS Insert or similar?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a .csv file that gets pivoted into 6 million rows during a SSIS package. I have a table in SQLServer 2005 of 25 million +  rows. The .csv file has data that duplicates data in the table, is it possible for rows to get updated if it already exists or what would be the best method to achieve this efficiently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comparing 6m rows against 25m rows is not going to be too efficient with a lookup or a SQL command data flow component being called for each row to do an upsert.  In these cases, sometimes it is most efficient to load them quickly into a staging table and use a single set-based SQL command to do the upsert.

Even if you do decide to do the lookup - split the flow into two streams, one which inserts and the other which inserts into a staging table for an update operation.

Comment: Very good point, the Lookup task is likely to be slow with this number of rows.  Staging & SQL is a good option.

Comment: +1 - I do this every day.  Insert to a staging table, run a compare using `EXISTS` to load from staging.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind losing the old data (ie. the latest file is all that matters, not what's in the table) you could erase all the records in the table and insert them again.

You could also load into a temporary table and determine what needs to be updated and what needs to be inserted from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Lookup task to identify any matching rows in the CSV and the table, then pass the output of this to another table or data flow and use a SQL task to perform the required Update.